# How to assign JSON to a field inside the function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to assign data that I get from the rest call, to 'myData' field instead of the manually created JSON below.

I tried,

```
'myData' : data,
```

And only got the Title row

I tried

```
'myData' : data[]
```

And got:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]
```

I tried

```
'myData' : [data[]]
```

And got:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]
```

None of them worked. How can I do this assign in Javascript?

```
makeProxyCall("http://localhost:9090/service/company/sites", function(data) {       
                $('table[data-table-name="dt-array"]').myDataGrid({
                      'myColumns': [
                        { 'sTitle': 'ID', 'sClass': 'essential' },
                        { 'sTitle': 'Location', 'sClass': 'essential' },
                        { 'sTitle': 'Timezone', 'sClass': 'essential' }
                      ],
                      'myData': [
                        ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
                        ['possum', 'raccoon', 'gravy'],
                        ['peanut', 'epsilon', 'flapjack']
                      ],
                      'isResponsive': true
                    });
                });
```

Comment: If the data is JSON you will need to parse it: `'myData' : JSON.parse(data)`.

Comment: You've told us a bunch of things that you've tried, but you haven't told us what the result was or how it differed from what you expected.

Comment: @Andy I am seeing "SyntaxError: Unexpected token o" in the debug console when type JSON.parse(data)

Comment: In that case, `data` contains an object and not JSON (the object may have been created by parsing JSON earlier)

Comment: @Quentin You are right, I edited my question.

Comment: "only got the Title row" — You still haven't show us what data is actually in `data`.

Comment: @Quentin This is what I see when I type data on console: [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

Comment: The hard coded stuff consists of an array of arrays. If you replace it with an array of objects, I wouldn't be surprised that it doesn't work as expected.